# How to change style in a head on click?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, styles, internals

On click I want to change the Internal style sheet that is in the "style" head. (I don't want to change it in Inline style!!) I managed to add the new divone css as text but I can't delete the old one (element.classList.remove ("# divone");). Is there an idlist.remove? ..., or any other way to accomplish this. Any idea or suggestion?
thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style id="style">
#divone{
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
#divtwo{
width: 400px;
height: 80px;
background-color: purple;
}
</style>
</head>
```

```
<div id="divone"></div>
<div id="divtwo"></div>
<button onclick="myFunctionTest()">Click me</button>
```

```
function myFunctionTest() {
    var element = document.getElementById("style");
    element.classList.remove("#divone");
    document.getElementById("style").textContent += "#divone{width: 400px; height: 35px; background-color: red;}";
}
```

Comment: simply add a new style properties to the same style tag and old style deceleration will be overridden. Why do you want to remove to old one?

Answer (score 1):

You try to delete **class** but use **id**

Do it as below. Change the id symbol `#` to class symbol `.` also change the DOM id to class name:

```js
function myFunctionTest() {
    var element = document.getElementById("style");
    element.classList.remove("divone");
    document.getElementById("style").textContent += ".divone{width: 400px; height: 35px; background-color: blue;}";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style id="style">
.divone{
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="divone">hello !!</div>
<div class="divtwo"></div>
<button onclick="myFunctionTest()">Click me</button>
```

AS your comment do it with **ID**

```js
function myFunctionTest() {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll("#style")[0].sheet;
  for (var i = 0; i < element.cssRules.length; i++) {
    if (element.cssRules[i].selectorText === '#divone') {
      element.deleteRule(i);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("style").textContent += "#divone{width: 400px; height: 35px; background-color: blue;}";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style id="style">
    #divone {
      width: 500px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<div id="divone">hello !!</div>
<div id="divtwo"></div>
<button onclick="myFunctionTest()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: I need it with id ..., as I mentioned in the question if there is something like element.idList.remove ("divone");

Comment: In your example the style #divone is just duplicating so I have two #divone in style. The old #divone should be removed and replaced with the new #divone, but the other #divtwo..., will not be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You give CSS in onclick of button. Try below code.

```js
  

  function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('button').style.cssText = 'background-color: green; color: white; font-size: 44px';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style id="style">
.divone{
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="divone" id="button">hello !!</div>
<div class="divtwo"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: No jquery, i would ask you if you can turn this into javascript?

Comment: I need changes to the head-internal style, not the inline style

Answer (score 0):

```
  function myFunctionTest() {
    document.getElementById("style").remove();
    var css = '#divone{width: 400px; height: 35px; background-color: red;}',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsById('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

   head.appendChild(style);

   style.type = 'text/css';
   if (style.styleSheet){
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
   style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
   } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
     }


  }
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the whole style but just #divone and replace it with another  #divone, because style contains others like #divtwo....., many...